# Solving differential equation n

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Which of the following is the solution for

$$u(x) = x + \int_0^x (t-x)u(t) dt \ ?$$

The answer says it is $u(x) = \sin x$. Could someone explain why?

Comment: Have you evaluated the integral to see what equation you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating once gives 
$$
u'(x)=1-\int_0^xu(t)dt
$$
and again
$$
u''(x)=-u(x)
$$
with initial conditions $u(0)=0$ and $u'(0)=1$ which is the classical mathematical oscillator equation.

---

In general, one knows from partial integration that 
\begin{align}
u(x)&=u(0)+\int_0^xu'(t)dt\\
&=u(0)-\int_0^x(-1)·u'(t)dt\\
&=u(0)-[(x-t)u'(t)]_{t=0}^x+\int_0^x(x-t)·u''(t)dt\\
&=u(0)+x·u'(0)+\int_0^x(x-t)·u''(t)dt
\end{align}
which is the Taylor or MacLaurin formula of degree 1 with integral remainder term. Again comparing with the given formula one identifies $u''=-u$ and the initial conditions $u(0)=0$, $u'(0)=1$.

Comment: Could you explain why differentiating the integral part gives $-\int_0^x u(t) dt$?

Comment: I thought when you differentiate $\int_0^xg(t)dt$ you get $g(x)$. Here $g(t)=(t-x)u(t)$. Shouldnt the derivative of the integral be $g(x)=(x-x)u(x)=0$?

Comment: You get also to differentiate the integrand, the derivative of $(t-x)$ is $-1$.

Comment: Or to be more intuitive, the integral value at $x+dx$ is $$\int_0^{x+dx}(t-x-dx)u(t)dt=\int_0^x(t-x)u(t)dt+\int_0^{dx} su(x+s)ds-\int_0^{x+dx}(-dx)u(t)dt$$

Answer (score 1):

First we rewrite your equation:

$$u(x) = x + \int_0^x tu(t) dt-\int_0^x xu(t) dt = x + \int_0^x tu(t) dt-x\int_0^xu(t) dt $$

Now we apply the fundamental theorem of calculus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) in combination with the product rule of differentiation.

$$u'(x)=1+xu(x)-\int_0^xu(t)dt+xu(x)=1-\int_0^xu(t)dt$$

Now, we differentiate this again using the fundamental theorem of calculus.
$$u'(x)=-u(x)$$

This is the differential equation, which has the general solution $u(t)=a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see this is to plug in $u(x) = \sin x$ and see that it solves your equation, but this is not very illuminating.  A second way to see that $u(x) = \sin x$ is a solution, is to take your equation and differentiate both sides twice.  By the fundamental theorem of calculus, you obtain
\begin{align*}
u''(x) = -u(x).
\end{align*}
Moreover, from the equation you have $u(0) = 0, u'(0) = 1$.  The general solution to the above ODE is $u(x) = a\sin x + b \cos x$.  The initial conditions $u(0) = 0, u'(0) = 1$ imply that $a = 1, b = 0$ so that $u(x) 
= \sin x$.  Finally, a third way to derive $u(x) = \sin x$ is via Picard iteration.  One can show that the integral equation
\begin{align*}
u(x) = x + \int_0^x ( t - x) u(t) dt, 
\end{align*}
has a unique fixed point in $C([0,1])$ (via contraction mapping).  Moreover, 
the sequence of functions defined by $u_0(x) = 0$, 
\begin{align*}
u_n(x) = x + \int_0^x (t-x) u_{n-1}(t) dt, \quad n \geq 1,
\end{align*}
converges uniformly to the solution $u$ on $[0,1]$.  Doing the first few iterates, you see that 
\begin{align*}
u_1(x) &= x, \\
u_2(x) &= x - \frac{x^3}{3!}, \\
u_3(x) &= x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!},
\end{align*}
and so on, so that you get the Taylor series for $\sin x$.